# angular, polyfills, import declaration

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, polyfills

In the polyfills.ts file I have the below import declaration:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
```

Now, I want to import it only if a browser is IE11 or less, so I added this statement:

```
var version = detectIE();

if (version && version < 12) {
   import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 }
```

but now I get the below syntax error:

*An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module*

Is it possible to make conditional import?

Comment: Maybe this page could help you : http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-conditional-imports/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally import any polyfills this way, because the `polyfills` bundle is generated at build time.

If you want to polyfill based on the user browser take a look at [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/).

> Polyfill.io reads the User-Agent header of each request and returns polyfills that are suitable for the requesting browser. Tailor the response based on the features you're using in your app,